# Why doesn't object[undefined] work in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I thought all values in between [ ] were converted to strings, why isn't `undefined` converted to `"undefined"`?

```
var a={};
a[undefined];
Object.keys(a).length===0
```

Comment: You're not modifying the object; how did you expect anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assumption that all values between `[]` are converted to strings is incorrect.

That being said, what you're doing **would** work, if you actually assigned anything to your `undefined` key, but you aren't.

```
var a = {};
a[undefined] = 1;
Object.keys(a).length === 1;
```

Or even

```
var a = {};
a[undefined] = undefined;
Object.keys(a).length === 1;
```

If you don't assign a value to the key in a hash, the key is not retained.

**EDIT**

It's interesting how this language works. When you declare a variable without a value, JS initializes it with a value of `undefined`

```
var x;
console.log(x); //undefined
```

But when you attempt to declare a key on an object without assigning it to a value, then it is not initialized with a value of `undefined`;

```
var x = {};
x[1];
Object.keys(x).length === 0;
```

Also, just for fun, it should be easy to see from the above that the following is true:

```
var x; //initializes to undefined
var y = {};
y[undefined] = x;
Object.keys(y).length === 1;
```

Comment: Oh! thanks, I actually thought I read it in a book that they were, I'll have to check it. I'm very confused as to why your second example works

Comment: The second example works because you are assigning a value of `undefined` to the key `undefined` on the object `a`. `undefined` is a  valid value to be assigned in JavaScript. Nothing (i.e. no assignment) is not a valid value.

Comment: Oh my bad! I thought I was assigning a value, I originally tried it with an array and it did not work so then I made that an example with an object and messed up. But now I realize the undefined attribute wasn't showing up in the console because It is was array. anyways thank you!

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is that `x[1]` is not a declaration at all, rather it's an expression.

Comment: That's very interesting! Although I think I'd rather it be this way

Answer (score 0):

I think you've basically found an edge case.

If I had a variable `a` that was undefined, calling `myObject[a]` should also return `undefined`, like you're referencing an object property that isn't there.  Hardcoding undefined probably is equivalent to the interpreter as using an undefined variable.